# Создание страниц html

Tags: php, html

Есть список ключевиков **keywords.txt**.

Пример:

- key 1
- key 2
- key3...

Есть скрипт generator.php.

При обращении к скрипту выдает текст:

```
generator.php?=key+1
```

Как сделать, чтобы ключи брались по одному из списка keywords.txt и обращались к скрипту generator.php? Нужно, чтобы при обращении каждого ключевика создавался файл `key-1.html`, `key-2.html` с текстом, который выдает скрипт generator.php.

**Обновление**

```
$f = file('keywords.txt');
foreach ($f as $line_num => $line) {
  $c = file_get_contents("http://bla-bla.yep/generator.php?=".$line);
  file_put_contents("key-".$line_num.".html", $c);
}
```

1) Косячит с ключами при создании страницы:

```
keywords.txt
serila online
smotret fim seichas
```

Получается так:

```
key-0.html
key-1.html
```

А надо так:

```
key-serila-online.html
key-smotret-fim-seichas.html
```

2) При парсинге берет только первое слово до пробела

```
serila
```

А надо (`serila online`).

```
smotret
```

А надо (`smotret fim seichas`).

Comment: Может кто помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то тогда в консоли вот так

```
l=0; for i in `cat keyword.txt`; do l=$((l+1)); wget "http://localhost/generator.php?=$i" -O "key-$l.html"; done
```

**Обновление**

Ну раз у Вас нет линукса... тогда пишите на php. Только если файл большой, то может работать плохо (лимит на 30 секунд никто не отменял).

```
$f = file('keywords.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
  $c = file_get_contents("http://bla-bla.yep/generator.php?=".$line);
  file_put_contents("key-".$line_num.".html", $c);
}
```

Но я давно на пхп не писал, собрал по хелпам.

улучшаем. Раз в запросах есть пробелы (а там могут быть и другие символы), то делаем кодирование с помощью [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php).
Эту же функцию будем использовать и для имени файла.

```
$f = file('keywords.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
  $fn = urlencode($line_num);
  $c = file_get_contents("http://bla-bla.yep/generator.php?=".$fn);
  file_put_contents($fn.".html", $c);
}
```

Comment: Это все хорошо, а в php как это реализовать?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Обновил ответ